# How can I load into a different view in a popover?

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

I have some code that opens a popover window that displays some text. This is done by an action segue rather than actual code in a storyboard. Is there any way, that I can load into a different view by pressing a button on the popover view and have it load into the next view? I've tried using another action segue, but it puts a popover into my current popover over the button that I press. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "load into the next view"?  I'm having a little trouble visualizing what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you be a little more specific or show some kind of graphic that explains what you mean?

Comment: @Bob I'm saying, to change which view is being shown in the popover. Like, for instance, I have my current view, and after a button press it dismisses (or hides) the current view and shows the newView in place of where the previous view was. So essentially, pressing a button and just showing a completely different view that I assign to it.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing can't be done with just storyboards; some code will be necessary.
Here's how I would do this:  instead of trying to use two separate popovers, use one popover with kind of a "nested" setup.  The popover's content view controller would contain, say, a `Page1ViewController` and a `Page2ViewController`.  When first displayed, the main controller would install page 1's view.  You could maybe wire the action from page 1's button directly to the main controller, but I recommend that you use delegation for this.  Create a protocol that's something like `Page1ViewControllerDelegate` and adopt the protocol in your main controller, then in the delegate method for `page1ControllerRequestTransition(_:)` or whatever you choose, just grab the page 1 view out and swap the page 2 view in.  You can even have the two views be different sizes; the popover will automatically adjust itself.

Oh, and don't forget to disable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and add appropriate constraints to fix the four sides of each page's view.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out later!

Comment: Good luck.  Let me know how it goes and if you need more help.

Comment: Is there any way you could provide me with an 'sample' project? I've been having issues really understanding what you mean by each of these. Thanks! @Bob

Comment: Have a look at this public-domain example: [NestedPopoverViewControllers](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83lexh8n80phkdu/NestedPopoverViewControllers.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Any questions about the sample?